# Laravel Eager Loading, only when ids are available

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I have a table like this:

```
payments
   -id
   -client_id
   -vendor_id
   -product_id
   -item_id
   -..._id
```

Using Laravel's eager loading, I can do this ->load('client', 'vendor' ... ) and load the relationships for all the returned rows of `payments`. But I've noticed that for example when there are no values in `payments` for `vendor_id` the eager loading query for the "vendor" relationship still happens, as below:

```sql
select * from `vendors` where `vendors`.`id` in ('')
```

The `in ('')` I understand should be filled with the values for `vendor_id` in the `payments` table, but since there were none the above query should not happen, right?! Is that a bug in Laravel?

The problem is that i got like 20 `[x]_id` columns in this `payments` table, and in each row only a couple (varies for each row) `[x]_id` columns have values, and I don't want to make 20 extra eager-loading queries, just the ones needed based on the actual existence of these ids!

Comment: This doesn't seem like a bug, but is most certainly something that can be optimized. I would suggest making a pull request or issue on [the Laravel framework repository](https://github.com/laravel/framework).

Comment: What's your exact Laravel version?

Comment: What version are you on? Anything >= 4.2.17 should already be translating the empty wherein clause to "0=1".

Comment: I am using Laravel 5.5!

Comment: This has been [fixed](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/26992) for lazy loading but not for eager loading. I'll take a look at it.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir I think you've already fixed it for eager loading, as well: [PR merged into 5.7.20](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/26903) . But, this doesn't help the OP much at 5.5. Just gives him hope for the future. :)

Comment: @patricus The query with the `where 0 = 1` clause should be quite fast, but it is still executed when it wouldn't have to be.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir Yeah. My original comment was just going on memory that wherein shortcuts empty arrays. When I tested a relationship and saw that it wasn't doing that, that's when I went into the code to find the issue, and then checked to see if it was fixed, and found your PRs. As far as a solution for the OP, not much to do but upgrade, and that's not a very helpful answer unfortunately. :(

Answer (score 0):

When you are doing `lazy` eager loading, laravel does not know if records are present or not. If not present laravel returns empty collection.

If you want to filter out at the start itself to show only payments having vendors and clients etc, you can do :

```
$payments : Payment::whereHas('vendors')->whereHas('clients')->get();
```

Above will give you only payments which contain at-least one vendor and 1 client.

Also, you are using `load()` which is lazy-eager loading. It is designed so that you can get the primary collection first and later when and if you need, then only get the relation collection.

Check for `with()` if you do not want to lazy-eager load.

Also, if you want to avoid eager loading,  you can go for `join` but again then you wont be using defined relations.

Comment: Actually I am using `with()` in the above situation

Comment: I believe that you need to actually use `with()` *alongside* `whereHas()` in order to eager load *and* only return models with relationships like that.